# Swift - Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' (Swift 4)

Tags: swift

On the last line it gives the error " Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' ", im a beginner to Swift and i have tried lot things but cant solve this issue

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> String{
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is trying to return a `String` yet the value you are actually trying to return is a `[String]`

Simply change it to this:

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> [String] {
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName
}
```

Alternatively if you do just want to return a single string value then do this to return the first object from the array of strings (or whichever string you want to return)

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> String{
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName[0]
}
```

The `[0]` denotes which string you want to return from the array by it's index

Answer (score 1):

The method `components(separatedBy:)` returns a `string array [String]`.

You function's `return type` is `String` and not `[String]`

So there are 2 ways to resolve the issue depending on your requirement.

**1. Use [String] as return type of function, i.e.**

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> [String]
{
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName
}
```

**2. Return a particular value from shortName array, i.e.**

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> String
{
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName.first! //Make sure shortName is not empty before force unwrapping it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Apple Docs:

**components(separatedBy:)**

Returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator.

**Decalaration:**

> func components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [String]

So your function should be like this:

```
func shortNameFromName (_ fullName: String) -> [String] {
    var lowerCasedName = fullName.lowercased()
    var shortName = lowerCasedName.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return shortName
}
```